# XML Schema Restriction With Attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

In XML Schema, how to make element `Age` to have `restriction` to allow writing integer with maximum value of 10 and minimum of 1, inside element `Age` but also element `Age` to have attribute ?

```
<xsd:element name="Age">
  <xsd:complexType>
here i want to have restriction to control max and min value inside Age element
    <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

XML Code with no warning

```
<Age type="sth">
 5 
</Age>
```

XML Code with warning

```
<Age type="sth">
 22
</Age>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a "complex type with simple content". Here's an example:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="one-to-ten">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </
  </
</

<xs:simpleType name="one-to-ten">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
  </
</
```