# Element 'xxx' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got two errors I can't seem to solve and I can't find solution for my specific case...

So there are my errors:

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'enginecapacityType' is invalid. Element 'restriction' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'enginepowerType' is invalid. Element 'restriction' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

My code is down below.

Can you please help me solve the problem and explain why it occurs? Thank you.

XSD file:

```
    <xsd:element name="carCollection">
            <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="personalData" type="personalDataType" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="copyright"/>
                            <xsd:element name="car" type="carType" minOccurs="10" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="personalDataType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
                    <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="sex" type="sexType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="specialization" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="group" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="sexType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="male"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="female"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="carType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="brand" type="BrandType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="model" type="modelType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="enginecapacity" type="enginecapacityType"/>
                    <xsd:element name="color" type="colorType"/>
        <xsd:element name="enginepower" type="enginepowerType"/>
        <xsd:element name="production_year" type="production_yearType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="BrandType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="BMW"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Audi"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Skoda"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Citroen"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Fiat"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Kia"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Focus"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Skoda"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Toyota"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Lexus"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Ford"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="modelType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
                                <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="enginecapacityType">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
                                            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="colorType">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:attribute name="tone" type="toneType"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="enginepowerType">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                                            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="300"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="production_yearType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                    <xsd:minInclusive value="1990"/>
                    <xsd:maxInclusive value="2018"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="toneType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="mat"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="bright"/>
                    <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
                    <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<carCollection>
    <!--
                W tym pliku xml jest opisana kolekcja wybranych samochodow
    -->
    <personalData>
        <name>Łukasz</name>
        <surname>Skiba</surname>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <age year_of_birth="1998">20</age>
        <city region="Lesser Poland" motherland="Poland">Kraków</city>
        <specialization semester="1">Informatyka Stosowana</specialization>
        <group>WZISN1-1113</group>
    </personalData>
    <copyright xmlns:uek="https://www.uek.krakow.pl/">
        Wydział zarządzania, Uniwersytet Ekonomiczny, Kraków
    </copyright>
    <car>
        <brand>Ford</brand>
        <model>Focus ST-Line Business</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">1.6</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Black</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">125</enginepower>
        <production_year>2018</production_year>
    </car>
    <car>
        <brand>BMW</brand>
        <model>2 Coupe</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">1.8</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">White</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">180</enginepower>
        <production_year>2018</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Ford</brand>
        <model>Mondeo</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">1.8</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Grey</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">180</enginepower>
        <production_year>2018</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Audi</brand>
        <model>A7</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">2.8</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Black</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">220</enginepower>
        <production_year>2017</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Toyota</brand>
        <model>Auris</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">2.8</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Dark green</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">180</enginepower>
        <production_year>2016</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Fiat</brand>
        <model>126p</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">0.9</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Red</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">25</enginepower>
        <production_year>2000</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Citroen</brand>
        <model>C3</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">1.4</enginecapacity>
        <color  tone="mat">Grey</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">70</enginepower>
        <production_year>2007</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Lexus</brand>
        <model>NX</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">3.0</enginecapacity>
        <color  tone="mat">White</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">160</enginepower>
        <production_year>2017</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Skoda</brand>
        <model>Superb</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">1.8</enginecapacity>
        <color tone="mat">Blue</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">200</enginepower>
        <production_year>2016</production_year>
    </car>
        <car>
        <brand>Kia</brand>
        <model>Cee'd</model>
        <enginecapacity fuel="petrol">2.0</enginecapacity>
        <color  tone="mat">Navy Blue</color>
        <enginepower power ="horsepower">200</enginepower>
        <production_year>2017</production_year>
    </car>
</carCollection>
```

Comment: Tip: use auto-formatting in an editor D:

Comment: It doesn't work. Used xml format in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare these elements as having a "complex type with simple content". See here for an example: [XML Schema Restriction With Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431937/xml-schema-restriction-with-attribute/15432972#15432972)

Perhaps like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="capacityType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="fuelType">
   <xs:restriction base="xsstring">
      <xs:enumeration value="petrol"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="diesel"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="engineCapacityType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="capacityType">
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="fuelType" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I don't really understand it... Could you please show me how would it look like on my code in those two places I have problem with?

Comment: I've shown possible code for one. I like to ensure that people understand the answer rather than just copying it, so I've left you to do the other one yourself.